# how to compare instances/count of a property to a per-page header value

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I am trying to run a test in Postman that will check:

> count(product.id) = responseHeader("per-page")

The default "per-page" is 30.
The schema for my {/product} endpoint looks like this:

```
{
    id (number, optional),
    name (string, optional),
    product_type (string, optional) = ['day', 'week', 'month'],
    supply_commencement_date (string, optional),
    supply_end_date (string, optional),
    delivery_period (string, optional),
    bid_sweep (number, optional),
    offer_sweep (number, optional),
    bid_qty (number, optional),
    best_bid_price (number, optional),
    offer_qty (number, optional),
    best_offer_price (number, optional),
    last_settle_price (number, optional)
}
```

After trying a few variations, I think I've finally got the script 90% complete...

```
pm.test("product id count matches ppg 00", function () {
    var ppg = pm.response.headers.get("per-page");
    var count = pm.response.json().map(product => product.id);
    pm.expect(ppg).to.eql(count.length);
});
```

However this returns **AssertionError: expected '30' to deeply equal 30** which I'm guessing means it is reading the header value as a string, so won't match my id count. 

I'm  hoping someone can either: 
* validate my thinking and if I'm right please advise how I would convert "per-page" to an integer; or 
* offer a better way to achieve the desired result. 

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: I have also tried using...

```
pm.expect(ppg === count.length);
```

Which says it is successful, but then so is...

```
pm.expect(ppg > count.length);
```

So I don't have much faith in these snippets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following options will provide an integer rather than a string. Please keep in mind this code does not type verification in advance so won't capture edge cases that do not produce a parsable string.

**Change**

```
var ppg = pm.response.headers.get("per-page");
```

**To**

```
var ppg = +pm.response.headers.get("per-page");
```

**Or**

```
var ppg = parseInt(pm.response.headers.get("per-page"));
```

Comment: thanks @randy-casburn, you made that look very easy. going forward, i'm going to use parseInt() as a reminder of what I'm doing until I'm more familiar with json.

Comment: Glad to help. You can use `parseFloat()` in the case of floating point numbers too.